# Checking for any 3 concecutive consonants

Tags: java, string, char

I have a code that checks if there are three THE SAME consecutive consonants in a string. It looks like this:

```
    String cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"; 
    char[] consonants = cons.toCharArray();

        int z = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your word!");
        String word = scan.next().toLowerCase();
        int length = word.length();
        char[] ch = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < length-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
                if ((ch[i] == consonants[j]) &&
                        (ch[i + 1] == consonants[j])
                        && (ch[i + 2] == consonants[j])) {
                    z++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (z == 1)
                break; 
        }
        if (z == 1) {
            System.out.println("Three consecutive consonants here!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is fine!");
        }
```

But I would like to check for ANY three consecutive consonants. To find words like - Christmas, country, children, school etc.

And not sure how should I change this code to do it. Can you help?

Comment: what did you mean did you mean to check for example `bcd` exist three times in your String or what?

Comment: Just one time - three consecutive consonants

Comment: i really cant arrive to understand your question, can you provide some example so i can understand ?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way to go about this would be to loop through the word you want to search through by character. Every time the letter that you are currently on is in the consonants array, add one to `z`. Every time that the letter that you are currently on is not in the consonants array, set `z` to zero. If at any point, `z` is equal to three, than you know that the string you are searching has 3 consonants in a row, and you can break out of the loops. If you get the end of the loop and `z` never reached three, than you know that the string you are searching does not have three consecutive consonants. I hope this helped, and good luck with the coding!

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the String documentation, especially the contains() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to manage if you declare yourself an auxiliary method like `private static boolean isConsonant(char ch)`. This method will contain a loop over your `consonants` array and return `true` is the argument is the same as one of the consonant.

Now in your main program you can loop over the chars of the entered word while keeping a count of consecutive consonants. I will take `country` as an example. You take `c`, your method should tell you it’s a consonant, so increase the count to 1. `o` is not, so reset to zero. Do the same for `u` (doesn’t change anything, but it’s easiest just to do it). Now come `n`, `t` and `r`, so your count goes up to 1, then 2, then 3. When it reaches 3, you’re done since you know you had 3 consecutive consonants.

Inside your loop you will call your method in an `if`-`else` statement like `if (isConsonant(ch))`… You will have another `if` statement to see if the count is 3 — either inside or after the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked for how your code could be changed to make it work, so the following is based on your code and will work:

```
String cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"; 
char[] consonants = cons.toCharArray();

int z = 0;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your word!");
String word = scan.next().toLowerCase();
int length = word.length();
char[] ch = word.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    boolean isConsonant = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
        if (ch[i] == consonants[j]) {
            isConsonant = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isConsonant) {
        z++;
        if (z == 3)
            break;
    } else {
        z = 0;
    }
}
if (z == 3) {
    System.out.println("Three consecutive consonants here!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It is fine!");
}
```

The code now checks char by char if it is one of the consonants. If it is the consonant counter `z` is increased. As soon as the counter reaches `3` the for loop is quit and whenever a character is found that is not a consonant the counter is reset to zero.

But the check can be very easily accomplished using regular expressions:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your word!");
String word = scan.next().toLowerCase();
if (Pattern.compile("[a-z&&[^aeiuo]]{3}").matcher(word).find()) {
    System.out.println("Three consecutive consonants here!");
} else {
    System.out.println("It is fine!"); 
}
```

`[a-z]` is any character from a to z, `[^aeiuo]` is any character except the vowels. The intersection of both is done using `&&` and the resulting `[a-z&&[^aeiuo]]` represents consonants. As we are looking for three consecutive consonants `{3}` is added accordingly.

Here you can find detailed info on regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will this regex version work for a Russian variant? If I write it like... Pattern.compile("[а-я&&[^aeёиоуыя]]{3}").matcher(word).find())

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use nested for loop. You can achieve this by using indexOf() API to check if the value is present in your consonants string or not.

```
    String cons = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"; 


        int z = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your word!");
        String word = scan.next().toLowerCase();
        //int length = word.length();
        char[] ch = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ch.length-2; i++) {

                if (
                        cons.indexOf(ch[i])!=-1 &&
                        cons.indexOf(ch[i+1])!=-1 &&
                        cons.indexOf(ch[i+2])!=-1
                   ) 
                {
                    z++;
                    break;
                }
              if (z == 1)
                break; 
        }
        if (z == 1) {
            System.out.println("Three consecutive consonants here!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is fine!");
        }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling about this method.